# Underlined menu items jumpig when make hover

Tags: html, css, menu, edit, items

I am trying to underline menu items on hover. My code is the following:

```
a:hover {
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

When I use this code, the menu is jumping on hover.

My page:

https://www.webpreludi.online/

How to only make an underline effect witout jumping of the menu?

Comment: Move the padding-bottom property up to the anchor selector. a {padding-bottom: 5px;}

Answer (score 1):

You need to start with the border and padding on the original anchor otherwise you will always have that effect.  Start with your border transparent:

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: black;
  border-bottom-color: black;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">test</a>
```

Comment: Thanks :) simple way.

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-decoration: underline;` in your CSS and remove `border-bottom` and `padding-bottom` from your code.

Comment: Thanks and it is possible edit this underline ? 
change line thickness to 2px? or i try text-decoration-thickness: 2px; but not working

Comment: In a few browsers you can use `text-decoration-thickness` but it's rarely supported.

Another workaround would be to use `box-shadow`. 

Remove `text-decoration: underline;` and add `box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 white, inset 0 -2px 0 #000000;` Use the numbers to make the line thicker.

Comment: Please, I would need someone for similar small adjustments to the site, one of which is two or three things per page. I would be able to provide a financial reward for this. Wouldn't you like to cooperate?

If so, send me an e-mail to info@webpreludi.sk and we agree, I need such a micro modification and the code twice a week, you will tell me the price and I will send you the amount and you will then send me the code or modification. thank you very much for helping me

Comment: Hi plese it is possible make underline with efect? Please add a line effect to make the hover go from left to right?